# NodeJS On Run-Time Adding/Removing/Reloading requires WITHOUT server restart (No nodemon either)

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, content-management-system

I have a project for work where I am basically creating a form of CMS to which we will add applications as time moves forward.

The issue we're having is getting those applications loaded in (and more specifically modified) on run-time within the server.

The reason we're requiring this form of "hot loading" is because we don't want the server to restart whenever a change has been made, and more specifically, we'd like to add the new applications through an admin panel.

Nodemon is a useful tool for development, but for our production environment we want to be able to replace an existing application (or module/plugin if you will) without having to restart the server (whether it's manually or through nodemon, the server needs to be running at all time).

You could compare this to how CMS' like Drupal, Yoomla, or Wordpress do things, but for our needs, we decided that Node was the better way to go for many reasons.

Code wise, I am looking for something like this, but that will work:

```js
let applications = []

//add a new application through the web interface calling the appropiate class method, within the method the following code runs:
applications.push(require('path/to/application');


//when an application gets modified:
applications.splice(index,1);
applications.push('path/to/application');
```

But I require existing instances of said application to be adjusted as well.

Example:

```js
// file location: ./Applications/application/index.js
class application {
   greet() {
      console.log("Hello");
   }
}

module.exports = application;
```

the app loader would load in said application:

```js
class appLoader {
    constructor() {
        this.List = new Object();
    }

   Add(appname) {
        this.List[appname] = require(`./Applications/${appname}/index`);
   }

    Remove(appname) {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./Applications/${appname}/index`)]
        delete this.List[appname];
    }

    Reload(appname) {
        this.Remove(appname);
        this.Add(appname);
    }
}
```

The running code:

```js
const AppLoader = require('appLoader');
const applications = new AppLoader();
applications.add('application'); // adds the application created above
var app = new applications.List['application']();

app.greet();
// Change is made to the application file, .greet() now outputs "Hello World" instead of "Hello"
//do something to know it has to reload, either by fs.watch, or manual trigger
applications.Reload('application');
app.greet();
```

The expected behavior is:

```
Hello
Hello World
```

In reality, I'm getting:

```
Hello
Hello
```

If anyone can help me figure out a way to dynamically load in applications like this, but also remove/reload them during run-time, it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: if there is a way to run my application code without the use of require that would allow a dynamic load/reload/remove, that is also a welcome solution

Comment: Well, you can't technically "unload" code in node.js.  You can forget about it (leaving it in memory) and load replacement code if you want.  Any state in the previously loaded modules will still belong to the previously loaded modules unless you develop some coded mechanism for manually extracting the previous state and passing it to the newly loaded code.

Comment: I don't know what these dynamically loaded applications are, but if you put them each in their own process, then you could kill the prior process and load new code into a new one.  That would clean up the previous version of code completely.  You would, of course, have to use one of the many forms of interprocess communication to talk to it.

Comment: Code can be run without `require()` by manually reading the code into memory and using `eval()`, though I'm not sure it actually buys you anything over just using `require()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 how would you propose I go about this interprocess communication?
To give a tat more info on our software, we're about to make the transition to Office365 which has Microsoft Teams, and we'd like to add Tabs there for specific functionalities. A simple example would be that everyone has access to the application: Who-is-who, which shows every employee with some extra information about them. If someone from HR makes a changes (adds a person or changes some info on an existing person) those changes should appear in the whoiswho as well.

Comment: Part 2: Since we need our applications to be able to talk to one another, I am creating an engine that allows these to "communicate" to one another. And dynamically adding a new application to the list off applications is working just fine. the trouble, however, is removing a depricated, or updating a bugged application without restarting the whole system, which is something we'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I would start with [`child_process.send()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) and use that if it meets your needs as it's probably the simplest.

Comment: If you're putting each app in its own child process, then you can just send the process a message to tell it to clean-up and exit.  If it refuses after some timeout, then you can just kill the child process.  FYI, putting each app in its own child process also keeps them from taking down your server with poorly behaved code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @jfriend00 I realized I need to fix something else with my code, so his comments can still be useful for other people. As to my issue of unloading required modules or reloading them without a server restart, I figured out a relatively elegant way of making it happen.
Let me start by showing you all my test class and app.js and I'll explain what I did and how it works.

**Class.js:**

```js
"use strict";

class Class {
    constructor() {
// this.file will be put in comments post run-time, and this.Output = "Hey" will be uncommented to change the source file. 
        var date = new Date()
        this.Output = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds() + "." + date.getMilliseconds();
        this.file = global.require.fs.readFileSync('./file.mov');
        //this.Output = "Hey";
    }
}

module.exports = Class;
```

**app.js:**

```js
'use strict';
global.require = {
    fs: require('fs')
};
const arr = [];
const mod = './class.js'
let Class = [null];
Class[0] = require(mod);
let c = [];
c.push(new Class[0]());
console.log(c[0].Output);
console.log(process.memoryUsage());
setTimeout(() => {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(mod)];
    delete Class[0];
    Class[0] = require(mod);
    console.log(Class)
    delete c[0];
    c[0] = new Class[0]();
    console.log(c[0].Output);
    console.log(process.memoryUsage());
}, 10000);
```

Now let me explain here for a bit, and mind you, this is testing code so the naming is just horrid.

This is how I went to work:

## Step 1

I needed a way to separate required modules (like fs, or websocket, express, etc.) so it wouldn't mess with the whole `delete require_cache()` part of the code, my solution was making those globally required:

```js
global.required = {
    fs: require('fs')
}
```

## Step 2

Figure out a way to make sure the Garbage Collector removes the *unloaded* code, I achieved this by putting my requires and class declarations inside of a variable so that I could use the `delete` functionality within Node/Javascript. (I used `let` in my test code because I was testing another method beforehand, haven't tested if `const` would work again).
I also made a variable that contains the path string for the file (in this case *'./Class.js'* but for my explanation below I'll just write it in as is)

```js
let Class = [null] //this declares an array that has an index '0'
Class[0] = require('./Class');

let c = [new Class[0]()] // this declares an array that has the class instantiated inside of index '0'
```

As for the garbage collection, I'm simply able to do the following:

```js
delete Class[0];
delete c[0];
```

After this I am able to redo the declaration of the required class and subsequently the class itself and keep my code working without requiring a restart.

**Take in mind that his takes a lot of work to implement in an actual project, but you could split it up by adding an unload() method to a class to unload underlying custom classes. But my initial testing shows that this works like a charm!**

*Edit: I feel required to note that without jfriend00's comments I'd never have figured out this solution*

## Output

When the project start, it outputs the current time and the `process.memoryUsage()`

```
13:49:13.540
{ rss: 50343936,
  heapTotal: 7061504,
  heapUsed: 4270696,
  external: 29814377 }
```

during the 10 second wait, I change the `Class.js` file to not read the `file.mov` and say *"Hey"* instead of the time, after the 10s timout this is the output:

```
Hey
{ rss: 48439296,
  heapTotal: 7585792,
  heapUsed: 4435408,
  external: 8680 }
```